# React Native Firebase, google authentication closes app unexpectedly

Tags: android, google-authentication, react-native-firebase

I want to use react-native-google-signin but everytime I click on the button to do the login the application closes. The first time only appeared the loggin dialog box of google account and I sellected my google account (I am running on a android device), now it closes the app everytime I try to click on the button. I don't know where the problem is, it didn't show any error on the phone screen or on the console. I sucessfully put the facebook authentication with [the code that us provided on the site](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/social-auth)